# Did my answer get down-voted for being too flashy?

Tags: discussion

I just posted an answer which got down-voted and I'm wondering if the graphics upset the down-voter who as usual didn't leave a comment as to reason: [Set CPU governor to performance in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084727/307523)

Not wanting to upset anyone with my answers I'd really like to know what brought on the negative reaction?

---

**Edit:** Taking comments and answer into consideration I've edited the answer in the link above. When viewing the link you'll need to view the revision history to fully understand comments below.

**Edit2:** Following up on Oli's answer I put a script into the answer to prove Governor is being changed by kernel 1 minute into boot.

Comment: Isn’t your solution exactly what OP tried? Maybe go into detail what they did wrong. Also, is the (IMO slightly ranty) hint to the `cpu-frequtils` answer necessary? If anything it would be sufficient to state that one doesn’t need to install anything I’d say.

Comment: What’s the goal of the graphics? Does it anything besides confirming what you say above it? (I must admit, I see not even that.) Does it add to your answer, enough to justify an animated (!) gif to take up half the space of your answer?

Comment: It shows the clock speed dropping at 1m uptime. Not really that conclusive because intel_pstate can still boost up.

Comment: AFAICT the first paragraph and the GIF could be removed completely without losing any useful information.

Comment: @dessert I edited the answer to explain the GIF better. I removed references to `cpu-frequitls`. I'll try to implement some of the suggestions in Oli's answer after work.

Comment: @muru I added a script to the answer for those who would like to prove it on their own systems without using a CPU monitor.

Comment: +1 to both this and the other...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Haha Thanks! You are probably conditioned to my "flashy" answers though and don't give it a second thought :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Maybe.* Where n=1, and there's nothing obvious, you really need the person doing the voting to tell you.

What I will say about the graphic is it's hard to see what's actually going on because there's so much. It also requires you to infer the drop in clock speed came from *something* happening at 1m, which isn't clear. A graphic showing just the uptime and governor, it might be easier to grok. It'd take up less space too. *If* that was the problem, that might fix it.

And if a GIF's loops are non-obvious, a little progress bar along the bottom goes a mile in terms of usability.

Comment: Below the GIF I could have added: *The 3000+ MHz CPU speed at start up appears near the top. The up time appears near the bottom. When up time hits about 1 minute you see CPU MHz drop off*. I will see tonight if I can annotate GIF or add progress bar on bottom.

Comment: I added a script to the answer to show the exact second (it is 1 minute BTW) that the kernel switches governor from Powerformance to Powersave automatically. Contemplating this it makes sense to have a 1 minute CPU boost during boot up when hundreds of programs are initializing.

Comment: I managed to annotate the GIF but couldn't figure out how to add a progress bar to it. Thank you for your suggestions on improving my answer.